# Mathematic WYSIWYG html editor

Tags: html, math, editor, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a mathematical WYSIWYG HTML editor. So it has to be capable of producing well formed mathematical expressions like in this example:

http://www.blau-test.be/files/example.jpg ( the font really doesn't mather, considering it can be styled using css )

Pricing doesn't matter, but it can be free 2 offcourse. If it is , the creator can expect a large donation ;)

It should be capable of producing the most common math expressions available , if not all! It don't expect it to work properly on IE6 but IE7 and IE8 would be nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematicians swear by TeX as being the most effective way to describe complex formulae to the degree that the'll often use TeX notation when communicating via plain text.

There are a number of [different editors for different circumstances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor), but I've personally never seen a more concise, accurate, and on-the-fly modifiable means of getting idea to typography.

Comment: thx , that list made my day! :) There are some scripts that might do the trick!

Answer (score 3):

For very good WYSIWYG just fork [MathQuill](https://github.com/laughinghan/mathquill) from github.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [mathoverflow.net](http://mathoverflow.net). They handle math markup very well. [They use MathJax.](https://mathoverflow.net/faq#latex)

> MathOverflow LaTeX support is MathJax,
>   a method of including mathematics in
>   web pages using javascript.

Comment: Math.SE uses MathJax, which is better, but in either case they only *render* LaTeX, so no they aren't WYSIWYG editors

Comment: @Yi: If I am not mistaken, it shows a preview of the output as you are typing the codes. This may be sufficient for the OP.

Comment: it must be possible to edit / add them IN the browser , so purely on a webpage, not requiring some extra desktop plugin or such.

Answer (score 1):

If pricing really doesn't matter have a look at *Mathematica*.  It can export mathematical expressions in MathML which most browsers can present, either natively or with a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I felt someone should mention Design Science's product, [MathFlow](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathflow/default.htm).  I have no experience with the product, but the company has long been a supporter of MathML and related standards, and the products certainly merit some attention for a serious project.

On MathJax: The OP asked for WYSIWYG, and I'd argue that being able to quickly write out a math expression in ascii, latex or mathml and have it directly interpreted by a one-line script included on a page, provides as much or more immediate accessibility and feedback than a GUI interface.